# How can I cycle through items in a DynamoDB table?

Tags: python-3.x, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How can I cycle through items in a DynamoDB table?

That is, if I have a table containing `[A,B,C]`, how can I efficiently get item A with my first call, item B with my second call, item C with my third call and item A again with my fourth call, repeat?

This table could in the future expand to include `D, E, F` etc and I would like to incorporate the new elements into the cycle.

The current way I am doing it is giving each item an attribute "seen". We scan the whole table, find an element that's not "seen" and put it back as "seen". When everything has been "seen", make all elements not "seen" again. This is very expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest option is probably:

1. use scan with `Limit=1` and do not supply `ExclusiveStartKey`, this will get the first item
2. if an item was returned and `LastEvaluatedKey` is present in the response, then re-run scan with `ExclusiveStartKey` set to the `LastEvaluatedKey` of the prior response and again `Limit=1`, repeat step 2 until no item returned or `LastEvaluatedKey` is absent
3. when you get zero items returned, you've hit the end of the table, goto step 1

This is an unusual pattern and probably not super-efficient, so if you can share any more about what you're actually trying to do here, then we might be able to propose better options.

Comment: Im running things in an aws lambda function so speed is quite important. I have a dyanmodb table holding items that I would like to buy one at a time and in cycles. This table is constantly having its prices and other attributes updated and dynamic, my lambda function means there's no memory, which is why I want to do something like this.

Comment: Well, this would work but, of course, Lambda limits the life of your invoked function. Also, not sure what you mean by "my lambda function means there's no memory". By memory, do you mean state? Are you hoping to process each item with a unique Lambda invocation? If so, then looping like I suggested won't work quite as simply. You'd have to persist `LastEvaluatedKey` to another DynamoDB table (or elsewhere that's persistent, like Parameter Store) and have the next Lambda invocation read it.

Comment: but doing it your way, in final cycle I'll be making n seperate calls which would be much slower than scanning?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I personally wouldn't do a scan with Limit=1 if I needed to scan an entire table, but you asked for item A with your first call, item B with your second call, hence my suggestion of Limit=1. Obviously you can set any limit you like, whatever fits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to return items that haven't been seen would be to have an attribute of seen=no included when inserted.  Then you could have a global secondary index over that attribute which you could then Query().

There isn't an efficient way to reset all the seen=yes attributes back to no.  Scan() and Query() would both end up returning the entire table and you'd end up updating records one by one.  That will not be fast nor cheap with a large table.

**EDIT**
Once all the records have `seen="yes"` and you want to reset them back to `seen="no"`  A query on the GSI suggested above will work exactly like a scan...every record will have to be read and then updated.

If you have 1M records, each about 1K, and you want to reset them...you're going to need
250K reads (since you can read 4 records with a single 4KB RCU)
1M writes

Comment: What If I made the seen attribute a String sort key? Then I can do a query on the sort key which means I don't look through the whole table right?

Comment: That's exactly what my answer says...yes you'll be able to query for objects with `seen=no` the problem is resetting from `yes` back to `no` that you indicated was required.

Comment: I know, but im saying set seen as a key rather than some attribute, so you could efficiently query it.

Comment: @tomq again, that's exactly what the answer suggests...but it's only going to help you find records with `seen="no"`  resetting is going to be the problem...see edit...

Comment: what about moving the seen from one table too another as you scan with limit 1, then looking in the other table when this table is empty? would that be faster and more efficient?

Comment: nope, now you've double the writes as you have to do a delete + insert, instead of an update.